# Joint probability of $X,\max\{X,Y\}$

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be independent variables with geometric probability. Let $Z=max\{X,Y\}$.

It is known that the joint probability of $X, Z$ is $P\{X=a,Z=b\}=P\{X=a\}P\{Z=b|X=a\}$ when $a,b$ are nonzero integers.

I am stuck here. What I can't understand is why there is a condition of $P\{Z=b|X=a\}$. I couldn't find any known formula which can be used in this case. May you give me some hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Z=b|X=a)=P(a \vee Y=b|X=a)=0$ if $a >b$ and $P(Y=b)$ if $a < b$. If $a=b$ you get $P(Y \leq b)$.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was about the origin of the condition, e.g. how can I state that $P\{X=a,Z=b\}=P\{X=a\}P\{Z=b|X=a\}$?

Comment: That is by definition of conditional probability.  @sobakaliza

Comment: Ok, the definition of conditional probability makes sense. But I still don't understand why if $a=b$ you get $P(Y \leq b)$?

Comment: Maximum of $b$ and $Y$ is equal to $b$ if and only if $Y \leq b$. @sobakaliza